Help for fitting a S shaped curve...
(Warning: I have a few remnants of math, stats, and machine learning, but I'm far from an expert in this field, consider me a noob :)
I am trying to fit with a curve the following dataset which is basically an S-shaped curve (definitely asymmetrical) :

I've tried the 5PL curve fitting in GNU Octave, which outputs me these parameters :
A (Lower asymptote): 9.1224
B (Slope factor): 15.3925
C (EC50): 186.7906
D (Upper asymptote): 256.319
F (Asymmetry factor): 0.41681
Why the 5PL curve fitting model ? Because I've tried all the fit methods in https://mycurvefit.com , and I found the 5PL method to be the best fit there... But maybe it's the wrong direction/fit ?
5PL always gives me a plateau (the lower asymptote) for lower values of x, where in the dataset there is indeed a small growth I'd like to better fit with the curve ... :

My dataset shape is indeed very similar to the one described in this post : Curve fitting an asymmetric S-shaped curve with initially slow then rapid growth.
In this post, it is suggested to use such a generic sigmoid-esque curve:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + ae^{-k_1 x} + be^{-k_2 x}} + c$$
My questions are :

Should I keep on using the 5PL model ? If yes, how should I tune its parameters ? Should I weight differently the residuals for a given x value ?
Or should I switch to the suggested generic sigmoid-esque curve ? If yes, do you know any toolkit or online tool where I could quickly experiment this ?

Thanks !
PS: Here is the GNU Octave code I used for reference :
pkg load io

data = csv2cell('20_samples.csv');   % Load the file as a cell array
numeric_data = cell2mat(data(2:end, :)); % Skip the first line (headers)
x = numeric_data(:, 1)'; % First column, transposed
y = numeric_data(:, 3)'; % Third column, transposed

% Check if x and y have the same length
if length(x) == length(y)
    disp('x and y have the same dimensions.');
else
    error('x and y do not have the same dimensions!');
end

% Print the values of x and y
disp('x size:');
disp(size(x));

disp('y size:');
disp(size(y));

% Compute weights
n_points = length(x);
% weights = arrayfun(@(n) (n - 10)^2, 1:n_points);
% weights = arrayfun(@(n) abs(n - 10) + 1, 1:n_points);
weights = ones(size(x));
% weights(1) = 10;   % Higher weight for the first point
% weights(end) = 10; % Higher weight for the last point

% Define the 5PL function
function y = fivePL(params, x)
    A = params(1); % Lower asymptote
    B = params(2); % Slope factor
    C = params(3); % EC50 (inflection point)
    D = params(4); % Upper asymptote
    F = params(5); % Asymmetry factor
    y = A + (D - A) ./ (1 + (x ./ C).^(-B)).^F;
end

% Objective function for weighted least squares
function err = weighted_error(params, x, y, weights)
    y_fit = fivePL(params, x);
    err = sum(weights .* (y - y_fit).^2);
end

% Initial guess for parameters: [A, B, C, D, F]
initial_params = [0, 1, 50, 250, 1];

% Set optimization options to increase max evaluations and iterations
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals', 1e5, 'MaxIter', 1e5);

% Perform nonlinear optimization with the specified options
[opt_params, ~] = fminsearch(@(params) weighted_error(params, x, y, weights), initial_params, options);

% Extract optimized parameters
A_opt = opt_params(1);
B_opt = opt_params(2);
C_opt = opt_params(3);
D_opt = opt_params(4);
F_opt = opt_params(5);

% Generate fitted curve
x_fit = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
y_fit = fivePL(opt_params, x_fit);

% Plot the data and the fitted curve
figure;
scatter(x, y, 50, 'filled', 'DisplayName', 'Data');
hold on;
plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2, 'DisplayName', '5PL Fit');
legend('show');
xlabel('x (Concentration)');
ylabel('y (Response)');
title('5PL Curve Fitting');
grid on;

% Display optimized parameters
disp('Optimized Parameters:');
disp(['A (Lower asymptote): ', num2str(A_opt)]);
disp(['B (Slope factor): ', num2str(B_opt)]);
disp(['C (EC50): ', num2str(C_opt)]);
disp(['D (Upper asymptote): ', num2str(D_opt)]);
disp(['F (Asymmetry factor): ', num2str(F_opt)]);

PS: I just found out that smoothing splines, as explained in https://splinecloud.com/features/curve-fitting/#smoothing-splines do perfectly the job !
I just have to figure out how this is implemented !

